# Sorting in alphabetical order using Partition and Swap

Tags: c, sorting, partitioning, arrays, alphabetical

So my program is using partition sort to reprint 10 user inputed names into alphabetical order. ive never used partition sort before so i'm utterly inexperienced when it comes to figuring this out.

I'm using an example of a partition sort for numbers and trying to manipulate it to sort using strcmp.

what i have below is mostly all my code with the exception of the Partition function which is where im having problems. Can someone please help me understand how this sort works and how i can manipulate it to sort 10 names in alphabetical order?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEBUG_LEVEL 0

int partition(int a[], int left, int right);
void swap(int *a, int *b);

#define SIZE    10

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

char Names[10][10];
int count = 10;
int i;
int a[SIZE];

printf("Enter 10 names:");
for (i=0; i < count; ++i)
{
    gets(Names[i]);
}
printf("\n\n");
partition(a, 0, SIZE -1);
printf("The names in alphabetical order are\n");
for (i=0; i< count; ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n",Names[i]);
}
getchar();
}

 int partition(int a[], int left, int right) {
int i, j, key;

key = a[left];
i = left + 1;
j = right;
   while (strcmp(i, j) <0) {
while (i <= right && a[i] <= key)
 ++i;
 while (j >= left && a[j] > key)
 --j;
 if (i < j)
 swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
    }
    swap(&a[left], &a[j]);
    return j;
 }

void swap(int *a, int *b)   {
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: 1) When code calls `partition(a, 0, SIZE -1);`, the contents of `a` are not initialized.  2) `i`, j,` are `int`.  Calling `strcmp((i,j)` makes no sense.

Comment: ya so like i said what i did is copied this partition segment and then added it into my code hoping i could manipulate it to get it to sort words. would it be easier to use Quicksort instead of a partition sort? i appreciate your hint but im still lost seeing as though this is the first time ive been instroduced to sorting through any method @chux

Comment: This is not a question of introduction to sorting.  `strcmp()` is a function that takes the address of 2 strings.  Passing 2 `int` does not make sense.  Certainly your compiler must be  (or should be) providing warnings.  Posting code that readily gives warnings implies 1) you have not compiled code (that is a major no-no) 2) have not enabling warnings (enable them all) 3) working with an ancient compiler (get a new one) or 4) ignoring those warnings. (read them and act on them).

Answer (score 0):

A short explanation of this partitioning sort method with a link to a long article is to be found e. g. on Wikipedia: [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Quicksort).

The shown code cannot work, due to the reasons stated by chux and moreover because the recursive calls for sub-partitioning are missing. Here is a working version:

```
void swap(char a[10], char b[10])
{
    char temp[10];
    strcpy(temp, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, temp);
}

void partition(char Names[][10], int left, int right)
{
    int i, j;
    char *key;
    if (right <= left) return;

    key = Names[left];
    i = left+1;
    j = right;
    for (; ; )
    {
        while (i <= right && strcmp(Names[i], key) <= 0) ++i;
        while (j >= left  && strcmp(Names[j], key) >  0) --j;
        if (i < j) swap(Names[i], Names[j]);
        else     { swap(     key, Names[j]); break; }
    }
    partition(Names, left, j-1);
    partition(Names, i, right);
}
```